# Wrong Use Of "Unclear what you are asking" flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I have noticed that I've had a few disputed flags in a short space of time, and so I want to clarify if I am mis-flagging.

In a scenario like this: [What causes HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP - The server encountered an internal error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989395/hey-friends-http-status-500-unable-to-compile-class-for-jsp)

[image]

I saw the question in triage, and felt that it wasn't clear; and was severe enough to not warrant a "Should be improved".

**Should I have used "should be improved" / should I have used a different flag?**

Comment: I would have used the "Off Topic"/"why isn't this code working?" reason for the flag. The question is just an error message, without the code that produced the error. Even though "unclear what you are asking" does not seem unreasonable either.

Comment: For us <10k, can someone post a screenshot?

Comment: Is it possible to grab a screenshot of the original question? I only ask because in the attached image, it's a lot clearer what is being asked.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would have flagged for closure, using the "Off Topic/Why isn't this code working" close reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help **("why isn't this code working?")** must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

That's because I would not have noticed the code embedded in the error message due to the shoddy formatting, code which technically makes the question complete enough to get an answer.

An occasional disputed flag in review is not that big of a deal, especially on borderline questions.  Different community members are bound to see things differently, and "Needs Improvement," "Unclear What you are Asking," and "Questions asking for troubleshooting help must include these required elements" are not all that different in their intent.

For those who would say "that's why people who know the subject matter should be the ones to moderate such questions," it's not really reasonable to expect the community to spend heroic efforts to decipher poorly-written questions.  We still expect a certain degree of question quality from askers, independent of the subject matter.

Comment: +1 re: "heroic efforts to decipher" Nothing sends me away from a question faster than when I can clearly tell the OP took no consideration whatsoever to save others time. In most cases the OP could spend 5 minutes preparing something for the community. The flip side would require the community to each spend 5 minutes all reproducing the same thing. That is a lot of waste. Even if I am a domain "expert" (or at least capable of solving/answering) I will not because of the time required to simply reproduce the issue. Solving these are often trivial, reproducing them needlessly takes too much time

Comment: @TravisJ, this research will usually show up in the first answer submitted. It would be nice if askers were more thorough, but I doubt it would impact overall efficiency much.

Comment: @Jehan: This isn't about research. This is about question presentation. If a question is so poor that experts aren't motivated to answer it, then it's unlikely to have an answer.

Answer (score 13):

That question had two big problems:

1. The description of the problem was *awful*.
2. The formatting was *non-existent*.

However, it actually did contain all of the necessary information: the asker included the full error message and exception text. Indeed, two minutes after you reviewed it it was answered.

The proper category for such questions is "Should be Improved". I've edited the question to demonstrate this.

I also closed it as a duplicate; that would've also been an acceptable action, although I don't normally encourage people to search for duplicates when reviewing in *Triage* unless they have good reason to suspect the question is a duplicate from the outset.

Comment: That's the first time I've actually seen *source code* in a Java error message, though to be fair, my specialty is C#, not Java, and I would not have noticed the source code in the original question's formatting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It's common in JSP stack trace messages.  It's not something that happens *often*, but it can occur.

Comment: Should not compiler/IDE authors provide "click to post detailed high quality question on SO" button? :) Would really help a lot quality of many questions...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov- I need to think for this now! Great Idea BTW. :) :P

Comment: @Makoto: "Common" or "not often" .. which is it?!